# Update field in redis

Tags: redis

i'm developing an application that required big request to databases
so my solution is to set a cache version in Redis
my question is how to update a specific field in stored document
in my case to increment NBRView by 1

and thnx

Comment: just use `INCR NBRView`. When you need to increment something else than one, us `INCRBY`. http://redis.io/commands/incrby

Comment: Thnx but i have an object saved as json (string)

Comment: Then you only get read out the json file, change the field and write back the json string. Or write a Lua script for doing it and call this in redis.

Comment: there is no other solution to update it without get it and save it ?

Comment: Use a [hash](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-hashes) with a field for each property, then increment with [HINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby) command. Evaluate the option of using a document-oriented database, like MongoDB.